# Ошибка в скрипте шаблона ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, исключения

Необходимо было написать тестовую функцию в шаблоне Ember(`.hbs`) через тег `script`.

Код выглядит слещушим образом:

```
function showError(field_name, error)
{
    var target = $('[name="'+field_name+'"]');
    var root = target.parents('.field').first();
    var errCount = root.find('.focus-error').length;
    root.addClass('.has-error');
    target.addClass('.focus-error');
    if(errCount===0)
    {
        root.after('<div class="field-error">'+error+'</div>');
    }
    else
    {
        var fieldError = root.find('.field-error');
        var fieldText = fieldError.html();
        fieldError.html(fieldText+'<br>'+error);
    }
}
```

После обновления страницы появляется ошибка:

`Invalid or unexpected token`

Отладка ссылает на этот участок кода:

[image: Ошибка в отладчике]

Если же удалить эту строку, то ошибка ссылается сюда:

[image: Ошибка в отладчике]

Если удалить и ее, то ошибка исчезает.

Собственно вопрос - с чем такое поведение связано и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Возможно где-то выше в коде есть незакрытая кавычка

Comment: где-то раньше - до этих строк - выводится лишний символ `'`

Comment: @Igor до этих строк ничего нет, только html

Comment: @BwehaaFox, в приведённом Вами коде ошибок нет - можете убедиться в песочнице http://jsfiddle.net/15f9jbhn/ Значит, ошибка где-то выше (как уже отметили коллеги)

Comment: Возможно, в код попали невидимые символы - изучите проблемный кусок в HEX редакторе.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему проблема крылась в `ember-cli`. Оно реагировало на строки содержащие теги. Поэтому если, например, здесь:

```
root.after('<div class="field-error">'+error+'</div>');
```

удалить закрывающий тег:

```
root.after('<div class="field-error">'+error);
```

Уже ломалась компиляция приложения с отображением ошибки `ember-cli` на странице браузера.
И эта ошибка срабатывала и в случае

```
var a = '<div class="field-error">'+error;
```

и

```
var a = '<div class="field-error">'+error+'</div>';
```

С чем конкретно была связана изначальная ошибка, понять не удалось, возможно защита от встраивания стороннего кода в ember, но решением стало перенести скрипт сразу в сервисы. После этого ошибка исчезла.